# Bash Script If THEN Loop

Tags: bash

```
File"LstTmp1"
account,subID,.......
disney01,2c97927269c72f2c0169e2e9fb216f00,/disney01-test/tdsna/inbox,true
disney01,2c97927269c72f2c0169e2ea258a6f15,/disney01-test/tdseur/inbox,true
disney02,2c97927269a0039e0169a02628f32de4,/disney02-test/inbox,true
etc..
```

```
File"SubsConfig"
disney01,2c97927269c72f2c0169e2e9fb216f00,/disney01-test/tdsna/inbox,true
disney01,2c97927269c72f2c0169e2ea258a6f15,/disney01-test/tdseur/inbox,true
disney02,2c97927269a0039e0169a02628f32de4,/disney02-test/inbox,true
etc..
```

```
File"TransConfig"
2c97927269c72f2c0169e2e9fb216f00,2c97927269c72f2c0169e2ea06756f06,OUT,undefined
2c97927269c72f2c0169e2e9fb216f00,2c97927269c72f2c0169e2ea06796f07,IN,ArchiveCompleted-peter01-tdsna
etc.....
```

```
exec 5<${LstTmp1}
while read -u5 line
do
    accID='echo '$line' | cut -d ',' -f 1'
    subID='echo '$line' | cut -d ',' -f 2'
    LstTmp2=`cat ${TransConfig} | grep ${subID} | grep "OUT" | cut -d ',' -f 4`
    LstTmp3=`cat ${SubsConfig} | grep ${subID} | grep -vE "outbox|Arch" | cut -d ',' -f 4`

    if [${LstTmp2} == 'undefined' && ${LstTmp3} == 'true'] || [${LstTmp2} == 'undefined' && ${LstTmp3} == 'undefined'] || [ ${LstTmp2} != 'undefined' &&  ${LstTmp3} == 'undefined']; then
    echo ${accID} > ${SkipList}.tmp
fi
```

I am trying script to filter out the following

TransConfig and SubsConfig contains attributes of the accounts

Finally only accID will be write to tmp files

Error Messages

```
grep: invalid argument ‘,’ for ‘--directories’
Valid arguments are:
  - ‘read’
  - ‘recurse’
  - ‘skip’
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
grep: invalid argument ‘,’ for ‘--directories’
Valid arguments are:
  - ‘read’
  - ‘recurse’
  - ‘skip’
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
```

Is if statement got any problem?

Comment: Paste your script at https://shellcheck.net/ and fix anything it reports.There are multiple issues that will cause errors or misbehaviours.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed your script, but without reproducible example and without sample data it cannot be warranted it does what it its intended to do.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

LstTmp1='unassigned'
TransConfig='unassigned'
SubsConfig='unassigned'
SkipList='unassigned'

exec 5<"$LstTmp1"
while IFS=',' read -r -u5 accID subID _; do
  LstTmp2=$(grep "$subID" <"$TransConfig" | grep "OUT" | cut -d ',' -f 4)
  LstTmp3=$(grep "$accID" <"$SubsConfig" | grep -vE "outbox|Arch" | cut -d ',' -f 4)

  if [ "$LstTmp2" = 'undefined' ] && [ "$LstTmp3" = 'true' ] \
    || [ "$LstTmp2" = 'undefined' ] && [ "$LstTmp3" = 'undefined' ] \
    || [ "$LstTmp2" != 'undefined' ] && [ "$LstTmp3" = 'undefined' ]; then
    echo "$accID" >>"$SkipList.tmp"
  fi
done
```

The `if` condition can, and should be factored:

Lets define:

- `"$LstTmp2" = 'undefined'` as condition `A`
- `"$LstTmp3" = 'true'` as condition `B`
- `"$LstTmp3" = 'undefined'` as condition `C`
- `[ "$LstTmp2" != 'undefined' ]` is condition `!A`

What you actually wrote is:

`A && B || A && C || !A && C`

Which translates into boolean arithmetic:

`A × B + A × C + !A × C`

`A × C + !A × C` is factored to `C` as: `C × ( A + !A )` and since `( A + !A )` cancels itself, there is only `C` left to represent the whole `A × C + !A × C`.

Remaining totally factored expression: `A × B + C`

Which translates back into shell expression:

```sh
{
  [ "$LstTmp2" = 'undefined' ] && [ "$LstTmp3" = 'true' ]
} || [ "$LstTmp3" = 'undefined' ]
```

( *thank to [KamilCuc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64099980/bash-script-if-then-loop/64100995?noredirect=1#comment113352628_64100995)* )
Which can be shortened since bash evaluates expressions from left to right, as:

```sh
if [ "$LstTmp3" = 'undefined' ] ||
   [ "$LstTmp2" = 'undefined' ] && [ "$LstTmp3" = 'true' ]; then
  echo "$accID" >>"$SkipList.tmp"
fi
```

If it is not the intended logic, then it needs be fixed as well.

Comment: `Factoring` `&&` and `||` have like same associativity, so they parsed left-to-right (they actually separate commands, commands are executed in order). The expression is `((((((L2=u && L3=t) || L2=u) && L3=u) || L2!=u) && l3=u)`, _not_ `(L2=u && L3=t) || (L2=u && L3=u) || (L2!=u && l3=u)`. Ex. the initial `(L2=u && L3=t || L2=u)` part is just checking `L2=u`, the `L3=t` is ignored. So, the factoring is great and logic, but it doesn't apply to how shell parses it.

Comment: It worked after some tuning, If LstTmp2 is null, LstTmp3 are true, I use the following?
`[[ "${SkipLstTmp2}" == null && "${SkipLstTmp3}" == "true" ]]`